# Unable to open Terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am receiving the following error while opening the terminal in Visual Studio Code:

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294967295.

Can someone tell me what to do here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I Upgrade my vscode or windows or something and now my vscode terminals are giving this error as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in your settings, in `Terminal > External: Windows Exec`:

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe